# How do I contact an individual?

Tags: support

Is there any way to communicate privately/directly with an individual member? I'm aware of Chat but how do I invite someone outside of the context of the comments section?

Answer (score 4):

Contacting individuals outside of chat is not available, by design, despite many requests. Please see

- [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/272257) (answer: *nope*);
- [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/272257) (answer: *Instant messaging or private messaging is not available*);

etc.

On the other hand, you may [invite a user to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236515/272257) directly from the user's chat profile.